# iphone/ipad - How can I draw an CGRect imageview in CALayer?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, calayer, cgrect

I am trying to draw an image capture from ipad camera in CGRect and added it in CALayer but it is not working properly.it show only a blue screen.

Any body help me please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CALayer *sublayer = [CALayer layer];

sublayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;

sublayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 3);

sublayer.shadowRadius = 5.0;

sublayer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

sublayer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;

sublayer.frame = CGRectMake(30, 30, 128, 192);

sublayer.contents = (id) [UIImage imageNamed:@"BattleMapSplashScreen.jpg"].CGImage;

[self.view.layer addSublayer:sublayer];
```